# Rust: convert iter of &T to iter of T via cloning

Tags: rust

How do you turn an iterator that returns `&T` into an iterator that returns `T` via cloning?

Minimal Reproducible Example:

Consider an iterator, provided by `ndarray`, that returns `&Value` objects. Define a function that returns an iterator of `Value` objects.

```rust
#[derive(Clone)]
struct Value;

pub trait IterValue<I: Iterator<Item = Value>> {
    fn iter_value(&self) -> I;
}

impl<'cellref, 'cell: 'cellref>
    IterValue<
        std::iter::Map<
            ndarray::iter::Iter<'cellref, Value, ndarray::Dim<[usize; 1]>>,
            fn(&Value) -> Value,
        >,
    > for ndarray::Array1<Value>
{
    fn iter_value(
        &self,
    ) -> std::iter::Map<
        ndarray::iter::Iter<'cellref, Value, ndarray::Dim<[usize; 1]>>,
        fn(&Value) -> Value,
    > {
        self.iter().map(|val| val.clone())
    }
}

// ... impl for ndarrays of other dimensions ...
// ... and possibly Array<T> for other T that will be converted to Value ...
```

Error output:

```
error: lifetime may not live long enough
  --> src\lib.rs:22:9
   |
8  | impl<'cellref, 'cell: 'cellref>
   |      -------- lifetime `'cellref` defined here
...
17 |         &self,
   |         - let's call the lifetime of this reference `'1`
...
22 |         self.iter().map(|val| val.clone())
   |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ method was supposed to return data with lifetime `'cellref` but it is returning data with lifetime `'1`
   |
help: consider adding 'move' keyword before the nested closure
   |
22 |         self.iter().map(move |val| val.clone())
   |                         ++++
```

Comment: There is [`Iterator::cloned`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.cloned). Anyway, I don't understand what the issue is. You ask how to do something, then show code that appears to do exactly what you're asking, but you don't say what the problem with your code is.

Comment: Your MRE is missing a `struct Value` and an error output. I assume you are talking about `error: lifetime may not live long enough`, but it isn't mentioned anywhere. Also, it's nice if it's formatted via the default rust formatting.

Comment: I added the error output; if this isn't true please revert and post your actual output.

Comment: Either way, @cdhowie is right. Simply call `.cloned()` on your `&Value` iterator, which converts it to a `Value` iterator.

Answer (score 3):

Your code is way overkill for a problem that is already solved.

Every `Iterator<Item = &T>` can be converted to `Iterator<Item = T>` via [`.cloned()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.cloned). (if `T` is `Clone`, of course)

Like so:

```rust
#[derive(Clone, Debug)]
struct Value(i32);

fn produce_reference_iter<'a>() -> impl Iterator<Item = &'a Value> {
    const data: [Value; 3] = [Value(1), Value(2), Value(3)];
    data.iter()
}

fn consume_owned_iter(iter: impl Iterator<Item = Value>) {
    println!("Iter data: {:?}", iter.collect::<Vec<_>>());
}

fn main() {
    let iter_refs /* Iterator<Item = &Value> */ = produce_reference_iter();
    let iter_owned /* Iterator<Item = Value> */ = iter_refs.cloned();
    consume_owned_iter(iter_owned);
}
```

```
Iter data: [Value(1), Value(2), Value(3)]
```